# Is there a more efficient way to search for a record but only if it has associations?

Tags: postgresql, performance, foreign-key, query-performance

I'm using Postgres 9.5.  I want to select some records, but only if they have at least one association in another table.  I came up with this query:

```
select distinct m.name, m.id 
from machines m, parts rt 
where m.id = rt.machine_id 
  and m.name like '%Name%';
```

but I don't think this is particularly efficient, since if there are 50000 associations, I think they're all loaded and then "distinct"ed through, which seems a little inefficient.  Is there a more efficient way to check load a record but only if it has one or more associations?

Comment: is there an index on machines.name?

Comment: @McNets is it SARGable? ;)

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik a proper index is ;)

Comment: Hi, Yes, there's an index on the "LIKE" portion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way your query is structured, you can just write it using an [`EXISTS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) expression:

```
SELECT
    m.name, m.id 
FROM
    machines m
WHERE
    m.name LIKE '%Name%'
    AND EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM parts rt
                 WHERE rt.machine_id = m.id
               ) ;
```

If you want the query to be efficient, take into account that the most difficult part will probably be checking the machine `name`. Consider indexing `machines.name` using a [`trigram index`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/pgtrgm.html). Trigram indices allow for fast finding `LIKE '%something%'` conditions.

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;  -- Only needed if extension not already installed
CREATE INDEX name_like_idx 
    ON machines 
    USING GIST (name gist_trgm_ops);
```

Most probably, the database planner will make an execution plan where it will first find the machines whose `name` is LIKE '%Name%' (using the `name_like_idx` index), then, for every machine in this subset, it will check if there are parts associated with them; if so, they will be part of the result.

For efficiency, it is also assumed that there is also an index on `parts.machine_id`, because this will then be how PostgreSQL will efficiently check for the existence of the part. If `machine_id` is a [foreign key](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK), it is always advised to index it.

This query doesn't need `DISTINCT` (assuming that the `id`s are already unique).